# Authorize.net request amount rounding off 3 decimal points to 2

Tags: api, authorize.net

I am working on authorize.net php API and I found a problem there. I am sending $45.347 as amount value but it is rounding off to 2 decimal points($45.35). Is there any way to show the 3 decimal value?

Comment: No because currency values are to two digits of precision. You need to either round it up or down yourself before sending the value over to Authnet.

Comment: I also thought so as per their documentation. They are saying that the amount has the limit upto 2 decimal numbers

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for the advanced integration method (AIM)](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/AIM_guide.pdf) section on page 22 for the `x_amount` field only two decimal places are supported.

You must round your amount before submitting the transaction.

```
x_amount Value: Amount of the transaction.
Format: 15 digit-maximum, with a decimal point (no dollar symbol). For
example, 8.95.
Notes: This is the total amount and must include tax, shipping, and any
other charges.
```